# Creating Collection of Class Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using Entity Framework and LINQ together in my project. I'm trying to fetch some data with following syntax,

I'm using following models, I have `IList<TeamDetails>`

```
public class OrganizationDetailsVM
{
    public Guid Branch { get; set; }
    public IList<TeamDetails> Teams { get; set; }
}

public class TeamDetails : Team
{
    public IList<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to use following query to fill my `OrganizationDetailsVM` but I can't actually reach my properties inside of my **CounterDetails** or **TeamDetails** class.

```
var teamQuery = _dbContext.PerfTeams
    .Select(x => new OrganizationDetailsVM
    {
        Branch = filter.BranchId,
        Teams = new List<TeamDetails>
        {
            //**I want my team details here as list of my TeamDetails class**
        }
    }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

As I mentioned in comments, here is related PerfTeamMembers classes.

```
public class TeamMember : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(6)]
    public decimal StaffId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Teams { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**: PerfTeam class added, I've simplified my models for easily understanding.

```
public class Team : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TeamTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string TeamBranchId { get; set; } 

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string TeamDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TeamPeriod { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }

    public virtual TeamType TeamTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the source of these table? If those need to be populated from another table and have relationship with `PerfTeam` then you can include those tables using `Include`.

Comment: @user1672994 In my _dbContext I configured them with seperate Table which is PerfTeams, PerfTeamMembers, PerfCounterMembers.

Comment: And those don't have relationship?

Comment: Can you post the related code about the PerfTeam class, PerfTeamMembers class and 
 the PerfCounterMembers class? They contain the related properties for the New entity (OrganizationDetailsVM)?

Comment: @user1672994 Yes they have relationship with each.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I've updated my question, please check it.

Comment: @shadowman_93 Which class matches the PerTeams table? It seems that you forgot to post the PerTeams class, since you want to find properties from the PerTeams table, if you could share this class, it might be easier to fix the issue.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT you are right, I forget to add my PerTeams class. I named that class as Team. I've updated my post. Thanks you.

Comment: According to your table structure, it seems that you want to get the Team and the related Team Members (since the TeamDetail just contains the TeamMember), it that is the case, try to use the following code `var query = _dbContext.Teams.Select(x => new OrganizationDetailsVM() { Branch = x.TeamTypeId,Teams = new List<TeamDetails>(){ new TeamDetails() { TeamMembers = x.TeamMembers} }});` And, you might also change the OrganizationDetailsVM class to `public class OrganizationDetailsVM
{ public Guid Branch { get; set; }  public IList<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }`

Comment: Please add your comment as answer, so I can check it as a proper solution for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your table structure, it seems that you want to get the Team and the related Team Members (since the TeamDetail just contains the TeamMember), in this scenario, you could try to use the following code:

```
        var query = _dbContext.Teams
                    .Select(x => new OrganizationDetailsVM() { 
                        Branch = x.TeamTypeId, 
                        Teams = new List<TeamDetails>() { 
                            new TeamDetails() { 
                                TeamMembers = x.TeamMembers } 
                        } 
                    });
```

Besides, in the OrganizationDetailsVM class, you could also change the TeamDetail Property  to TeamMember, then, when you query the Teams table, you could directly get the related TeamMembers. Code like this:

```
public class OrganizationDetailsVM
{
    public Guid Branch { get; set; }
    public List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
}
```

the query statement:

```
        var query = _dbContext.Teams
            .Select(x => new OrganizationDetailsVM()
            {
                 Branch = x.TeamTypeId,
                 TeamMembers = x.TeamMembers.ToList()
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var teamQuery = _dbContext.PerfTeams.Include(p=>p.CounterMember).Include(p=>p.TeamMember). .Select(x => new OrganizationDetailsVM
{
    Branch = filter.BranchId,
    Counters = new List<CounterMember>(p.CounterMembers);//or whatever you called it in ef
    {
        //**I want my counter details here as list of my CounterDetails class**
    },
```